# add username and password one table and other data in another using node js with rest api

Tags: node.js, postman, rest

I have one model is user in that model I was added email, username, password and name , when I have insert this data using node JS with the help of rest API, so that condition all 4 records are stored in one table
but I want email and name is stored in registration table and username and password stored in login table ,when I put login request using postman it with username name and password credentials it gives the successful response.

I am new to Node

My controller is

```
exports.user_signup = (req, res, next) => {
User.find({ username: req.body.username })
.exec()
.then(user => {
  if (user.length >= 1) {
    return res.status(409).json({
      message: "Mail exists"
    });
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      } else {
        const user = new User({
          _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
          username: req.body.username,
          password: hash,
          email: req.body.email,
          contact: req.body.contact,
        });

        user
          .save()
          .then(result => {
           // console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
              message: "User created"
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          });
      }
    });
  }
});
};
```

My Postman post method is in JSON form

```
{
   "username":"tene",
   "password":"tene",
   "email":"tene@gmail.com",
   "contact":1234567890
  }
```

Comment: By table do you mean any sql table or in code base? Also please mention which database are you using, if any.

Comment: @ rED ,Yes I have used mongodb database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const { Schema } = mongoose

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    registrationTable : { 
      email: { type: String, required: true },
      mobileNo: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    loginTable: { 
      username: { type: String, required: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true }
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

It will depend on you if you wanna make registration and login table as an object or array, but this will sure help.

**required: true** will be for, you need that value necessary, if you dont want some value just remove this.

Comment: Sure sir I can understand how u define/declare schema but I don't understand how to fetch this data from database and postman gives the error like as Path `loginTable.password` is required." I updated the question and insert my some code and json data

Comment: is the schema updated? cause according to your error `loginTable.password` will come from when you use my schema not yours.